# How to connect to RDS mysql using php file in EC2 html folder

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am very new to AWS. I have set up an EC2 instance and installed apache and MySQL on it. I also created an RDS instance, and now I want to connect my RDS instance from EC2 through a php file so I can do CRUD on RDS MySQL database from EC2 url.
I am able to connect to RDS db from EC2 instance via mysql -habc.xyz.amazon.com -uroot -proot but error while through php file
I am able to do CRUD from php file locally on EC2 MySQL via:

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root','');
```

it's working fine for local MySQL dbs, but

```
$con=mysql_connect('abc.xyz.amazon.com:3306','root','root','');
```

error:

> Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Do you have mysql "safe mode" turned on in your php application?

Comment: No, sql safe mode is OFF...its working for localhost EC2 but not for RDS.

Comment: Please re-verify that the error message that you're getting is actually for your RDS instance and not your localhost server.

Comment: yes same error....I have two files in html/db1 and db2 ..db1 for EC2 mysql (working fine)  db2 for RDS mysql (error) ..

Comment: Then it seems that safe mode is ON somehow. If Amazon RDS is reporting 'ubuntu' as your username in the error, then it's ignoring 'root' in your php `mysql_connect` command.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: ok ..it seams logical but I couldn't able to find how to turn of safe mode of a RDS isntance..can you please help  me with that ,thanks

Comment: It is not on your RDS instance. It is a setting in your PHP app. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode

Comment: its OFF bro :(  .....maybe some other things need to be checked